# When coding a game, what am I supposed to use as units?

Tags: sdl, game-engine, 2d-games

I've been using pixels as units for aspects of my game such as movement, but I've been told that this is a bad practice. However, I've never seen a good explanation on what I'm supposed to do instead. Can somebody provide a good explanation on how to handle units in my games?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what units you use; they can be completely arbitrary. The only thing that you need to do is make sure that they are *not fixed to the screen pixels*, because you later find out you want to change the scale of things that are displayed. It's OK if the conversion factor happens to be 1; just make sure that the conversion *exists*, so that you can change it if you have reason to later.

(And, as a practical matter, don't make the conversion exactly 1 because that hides bugs if you forgot to convert in one place.)

- For 3D realistic games, a common unit is "1 meter". Real world units don't matter, but the idea is to use a unit that is similar to the size of objects in your world.
- For tile-based or voxel-based games, a common unit is the width of one tile. This also allows you to omit some conversions, but you're much less likely to have a problem tying to tiles than to pixels because tiles affect the game rules anyway.